# Pointers: Difference between *p++ as lvalue and rvalue

Tags: c, pointers

So I am confused about one thing about pointers. Lets look at this:

```
*p++
```

I know that operator ++ is "bigger"(sorry idk how else to say, i am not native english speaker) than operator *. So that means that *p++ is in fact percieved as *(p++). So what confuses me is differenet outcome when *p++ is used as lvalue and rvalue. For example:

If I want to sum all elements of array this will work fine(used as rvalue):

```
sum += *p++;
```

My question here is why this it first happens *p and then p++, when ++ is bigger then *. Why it wouldnt first happen p++ and then *p.

But if i use it as lvalue, it works as I expected to do. For example:

```
*p++ = round(*p * 100) / 100;
```

It first happens p++ and then this new number is given to *p.

Why these 2 thing are different, when it is used as rvalue and lvalue, i mean i am confused why this example with sum.

Thanks :)

Comment: You might confuse this as a order-of-evaluation problem when it really is a prefix/postfix increment problem.

Comment: can you explain this what i asked pls

Comment: `My question here is why this it first happens *p and then p++, when ++ is bigger then *.` Is just not happening. The increment has higher precedence and will be evaluated first, but it yields the old value as this is postfix-increment.

Comment: By "bigger" you mean "has precedence" (comes before) as in [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix `++` has higher *precedence* than unary `*`, so `*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)`.  In other words, you are applying `*` to the *result* of `p++`.

The *result* of `p++` is the current value of `p`.  As a *side effect*, `p` is incremented by 1.  With pointers, this means that `p` is updated to point to the next object in a sequence.  IOW, if you have this situation:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  +---+
      |
    +---+
 p: |   |
    +---+
```

then after executing `p++` (or `p = p + 1`), you will have this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
      ^ 
      |
      |
    +---+
 p: |   |
    +---+
```

This is true regardless of the type of the objects in the sequence, so the *address value* stored in `p` may be incremented by more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of operators tells us how to **structure** an expression. Parentheses can be used to show the structure, so `sum += *p++` is `sum += (*(p++))`.

When evaluating the expression, we use the **meaning** of each operator, also called its **semantics**.

- The meaning of postfix `++`, as in `p++`, is “Do two things, separately: Get the current value of the operand and use that as the value of this expression. And increment the operand.” Thus, with `p++`, the **value** of the expression is `p`, and **separately** `p` is incremented. The increment does not affect the value of the expression; it is `p` before the increment occurs.
- The meaning of unary `*` is “Dereference the pointer.” So the result of `*(p++)` is `*p`, which is the object `p` points to (without the increment).